# Understanding union types

Tags: pascal, unions

In Pascal it is possible to declare union types:

```
AnimalType = (Dog, Cat);

Animal = record
  name: string;
  case myType: AnimalType of
    Dog: (weight: Integer);
    Cat: (age: Integer);
end;
```

However, it is easy to violate the contract of `case`:

```
var
  a: Animal;
begin
  a.name := 'Kittie';
  a.myType := Cat;
  a.weight := 10; // There is no weight for cats!

  writeln(a.age); // Prints 10
end.
```

There is a semantic error in this example, but the compiler typechecks it successfully. Also, there is no error at the runtime.

So, does the `case` block exist only for the documentation purposes?

Comment: Both variant members are allocated when you declare a variable of this kind, hence no error. But it's not for *documentation purposes*, you just have to be careful what do you want to work with in this case. Although, it would be nice if the compilers reject such code.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of the `case` block. Does it affect something at all?

Comment: The only purpose is to let weight and age share the same memory location. It is up to the implementation to distinguish between the semantical difference.

Comment: @LURD Yes, but do `case` branches affect something? If I switch `Dog` and `Cat`, will something be different?

Comment: If you switch the order in case branch, nothing is different.

Comment: Are you talking ISO standard Pascal or some Borland derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, "no case blocks in variant records are not there only for documentation purposes". I say this because although the Pascal implementation you are using did not detect the fact that the program as accessing an inactive variant, other implementation do detect this error.

The long answer to your question is as follows.

Many people who are just learning Pascal don't realize that there are two major flavours of the Pascal language. There is ISO 7185 Standard Pascal (or just Standard Pascal for short) and there is Turbo/Borland Pascal (the most popular variant). So let me give you two answers to your question "So, does the case block exist only for the documentation purposes"?

The Standard Pascal Answer

Standard Pascal defines an error as "A violation by a program of the requirements of this International Standard that a processor is permitted to leave undetected". So yes, the program you have given does contain an error and yes the processor (i.e. Pascal implementation) you are using does not detect it, but other implementation will detect it, so no the case block in variant records actually has a functional purpose.

The Turbo/Borland Answer

As far as the Turbo/Borland Pascal flavours go, I don't know if none of them will detect this error, but even if none of them do, it's probably better to think of this as an error that they do not detect rather than as something for documentation purposes only. Saying something is for documentation purposes only, sounds to me like saying it was never intended to be functional.

Answer (score 0):

A union makes it possible to give a variable multiple types. In your example, `weight` and `age` are stored at the same location in memory.

If you want a 'typesafe union', you should use inheritance.

Comment: This is a poor answer. A union type exists so multiple types can live in the same box. A union of a String and an Int is a type that could have the value of "One" or 1. Pascal has a weird implementation (And in its defence it was one of the first). But the concept is neither analogous to inheretence or interchangeable with it. You can't implement union types with inheretence, and you can't implement inheretence with union types. But you can make things that behave analogous to it.

Comment: Its also worth noting that some use Union types as a form of boxing. So a string that is permitted to be uninitialized is actually a Union of String and Null (Ie in Crystal you'd define that as (String | Null, and static analysis at compile time will tell you off if you don't box it into a string with a null check before passing it to anything that cant accept a null.